# "! Extra }" due to c++ params when compiling Doxygen generated LaTeX

Tags: latex, doxygen

When running `latex refman.tex` I get an error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<recently read> \egroup

l.44 \end{DoxyParams}
```

I have upgraded TeXLive, tried tweaking the doxygen.sty and edited the output file by hand. It will compile if I remove the line with record id and just have `\hline`. However, that is not useful.

```
\begin{DoxyParams}{Parameters}
{\em n} & record id. \\
\hline
\end{DoxyParams}
```

Documentation in the cpp file for the method. Any documented parameters on any other function create the same error.

```
/**
     * Finds a record.
     *
     * @param n record id.
     * @return A thing.
     *
     */
    int Find(int n);
```

It seems to work fine with generating html. But, I need to be able to generate PDF docs.

Comment: This looks like the problem with the LaTeX tabu package. The newest version (after december 2018) of LaTeX have a problem with the tabu package. It is advised to use an older versions (i.e. e.g TexLive 2018). See also https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470107/incompatibility-of-fix-in-latex3-latex2e-in-respect-to-unmaintained-tabu-packa

Comment: I face a similar problem and I have upgraded to doxygen version 1.18.16 and the problem is solved, it includes a fix for the tabu package.

Answer (score 0):

I described a simple workaround [here](https://medium.com/@elnee/how-to-fix-doxygen-latex-errors-with-doxyparams-broken-tabu-package-3bca6ccefe7e)

Edit: from the answer to https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6904:
That solution is for Arch Linux. But it's pretty much the same across distributions or different operation systems. Difference is only where the tabu.sty keeps.
Copy-paste:

- Download that file: https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu/blob/master/tabu.sty
- Now navigate to /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tabu/
- Rename existing tabu.sty to tabu.sty.backup
- Copy downloaded tabu.sty with fixes to that directory

Comment: 1) what did you describe?
   2) links to external sources are not that good as
        a) as they might not be persistent
        b) might contain viruses (I don't imply that this is the case but nowadays one has to be careful).

Please include the text in your comment.